# PHP script for Plaid webhooks

Tags: php, webhooks, plaid

I've set up an account to try out and one of the most interesting part of their API is the webhooks. However, I haven't found a reference to how to 'catch' the webhooks using a PHP script. I imagine that it is something like:

```
<?php
//pseudo-ish code
$webhook = $_POST['webhook'];
$json = json_decode($webhook, true);

// code to save webhook data
```

Anyone have any ideas? [Here is the link to their API](https://plaid.com/docs/#webhook)

Per a comment, I tried:

```
<?php
$result = var_export($_POST, true);
$file = fopen("screenshots/test.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file, "testing:".$result);
fclose($file);
?>
```

and all that results is a file with the word "testing:array()" in it indicating that $_POST is empty.

Comment: Why not `var_export` the entire `$_POST` to a file and analyze the request? As far as I see from the docs you don't need `json_decode` you just get a POST request with `$_POST['message']`, `$_POST['code']` etc.

Comment: I'll try that and report back. Thanks

Comment: Updated the comment with my attempt and result. Still no joy.

Comment: That's because `var_export` outputs the result instead of returning it. Should be `var_export($_POST, true)` ;)

Comment: now it produces testingarray(). So, $_POST is empty.

Comment: So it leaves us with two possibilities, either it's a GET request, you can test that with `$_GET` or they're sending the payload in the body of the request, in this case try to `var_export` this: `stream_get_contents(STDIN)`.

Comment: $_GET and $_REQUEST both return empty arrays. stream_get_contents(STDIN) returns "false".

Comment: Now that's just weird, could you dump your entire `$_SERVER` and share it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API sends the payload as a JSON encoded string in the body of the request.

```
$data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input'), '"\''), true);
```

Comment: To save someone the trouble when they run into this, the string returned has a leading and trailing apostrophe, which causes json_decode to return NULL. Subsequently, you need to do something like `substr(file_get_contents('php'://input),1,-1)` to get it to work.